# using cypher foreach In neo4j .net client

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am using neo4j from C# with the Neo4jClient v 1.1.0.34 and would like to use foreach to update a value in multiple noted in C#, I have the following code:

```
graphClient.Cypher.Match("(u:User)-[:HAS_EMAIL]->(e:Email)-[:HAS_VER_CODE]->(s:VerCode)"
)
.Where((User u, Email e, VerCode s) => (
       u.id == user.id && e.address == email.address 
       && e.isVerified == false && s.expiry > DateTime.Now))
.Set("s.expiry = {now}")
.WithParam("now", DateTime.Now)
.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

As is, the code above is not setting the expiry field on any of the matching nodes.

I need to set the expiry field to the current date time, but I cannot figure out how to use the .foreach (and have failed to find any examples in C#), the .for each template is give like this:

```
.foreach (var item in collection){}
```

Thank you for your time,

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - total misunderstanding of your question.

Using `foreach` in Cypher is different to `foreach` in `C#`, what you need is a collection of what you're wanting to search through, :

```
public class IdAndEmail { int Id {get;set;} string Address {get;set;} }

var idAndEmails = new List<IdAndEmail>{ new IdAndEmail { Id = 1, Address = "a@b.com"} /*etc*/ };
```

Once you have that, your cypher becomes:

```
graphClient.Cypher.Foreach(idAndEmails, "x")
    .Match("(u:User)-[:HAS_EMAIL]->(e:Email)-[:HAS_VER_CODE]->(s:VerCode)")
    .Where("u.id = x.Id AND e.address = x.Address")
    .AndWhere((Email e, VerCode s) => (e.isVerified == false && s.expiry > DateTime.Now))
    .Set("s.expiry = {now}")
    .WithParam("now", DateTime.Now)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I'm not typing this somewhere I can fully test the code is right, in terms of syntax, but that should get you there.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. Actually the match as above is correctly returning the nodes that match the condition. if I then go over each returned node and make a separate Cypher query that matches that single node and call .Set("s.expiry = {now}").WithParam("now", DateTime.Now), the result is correct. However, I am making many calls to the database, instead of the more idea solution of running the cypher foreach in the initial cypher command.

Comment: Cool - in that case, I've updated my answer to be what you actually asked :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will not have time to try it until a couple of days from now though, but thanks a lot :) I will update this post when I do try it and thank you again :)