# How to use ForEach in .Net Client

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

How do I pass a list of objects into a ForEach query in the Neo4J .Net Client? The function signature only has one text parameter. Unwind takes in two parameters one for the list, and another for the unwound variable name:

ForEach:

```
client.ForEach("some text")
```

Unwind:

```
client.Unwind(activities, "activity")
```

Comment: Maybe this is related [foreach neo4j client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703103/using-cypher-foreach-in-neo4j-net-client).

Comment: I did see that. It must be referencing an old version of ForEach, because the latest one only takes a single string parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and (despite the other question) I don't think you've ever been able to. I can't find that overload anywhere in the codebase, even in April 2016 it doesn't seem to be there.

The only way at the moment would be to do:

```
var myArray = new [] {1,2,3};
client.Cypher
    .ForEach("(val IN $myParam | ...)")
    .WithParam("myParam", myArray)
    /// etc
```